# Cbind two datasets of different length based on same row value

Tags: r, merge, dataset, cbind

I am trying to bind two datasets of different row length based on the same row values.

For example:

```
a <- matrix(c(1,2,1,4,1,6,1,8,2,10,2,12,2,14,2,16), byrow=TRUE, nrow=8)
b <- matrix (c(1,100, 2, 200), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2))
```

I want to combine these two datasets and create a new column for dataset "a",
with the values of b$V2.

So for every a$V1 == b$V1, I want to insert the b$V2 value.
Meaning that for every a$V1 ==1, the value in the new column is 100 and for every a$V1 ==2, the value in the new column is 200. The new column should have the same length as a.

The

Comment: Can you show us your desired output? Are you looking for a simple merge? Try `merge(a,b,1,all.x=T)`.

Comment: This is what I search for, yes! 
I tried that for my original datasets and I get only NAs in the new column

Answer (score 0):

Another, yet less elegant and a bit longer solution than that of user2974951, is to use a `for` loop:

```
a <- cbind(a, vector(mode= "numeric", length= nrow(a))) # add a new column to a 

# assign the values to the new column
for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
  if (a[i,1] == 1) {
    a[i,3] = 100
  } else {
    a[i,3] = 200
  }
}
```